# Try to read Values in LOcal Group policy

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

I am trying to read two setting values in Local Group policy (gpedit.msc). The path is :

Local Computer Policy\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment

The Policy that I want to read are :
1. Perform volume maintainace tasks (Users assigned to it)
2. Lock Pages in memory (Users assigned to it).

I have searched the web (including all stackoverflow threads) and could not find a solution to this but could not get a solution to this. Below is the code I am using currently but it only returns me 7 values.

I am not sure if this is possible. Please suggest. I am using C# .NET as language and would prefer if possible be able to read these setting from a remote machine (so I am preferring WMI approach).

Also I only want to read values. Now editing or writing...

Please suggest..

- Girija

***Code***

```
private void Test()
        {
            ManagementScope scope =
                      new ManagementScope(
                          "\\\\localhost\\root\\rsop\\Computer");
            scope.Connect();

            ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM RSOP_UserPrivilegeRight");
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

            ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();

            List<string> val = new List<string>();

            foreach (ManagementObject mgo in queryCollection)
            {
                var d = mgo["Name"];
                val.Add(Convert.ToString(d));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Found the solution here: http://www.centrel-solutions.com/support/tools.aspx?feature=auditrights